# Gmail like loading resources

Tags: javascript, loading

I am trying to load js & css files like gmail do , I find this tutorial but this method work only for js files http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/loadingbars/ . So any idea how to do it for css ?? thx

Comment: have no code .. just asking :D any html file do the work just some css & js files

Comment: Check out my answer below. Let's try to solve this one out. I'm also interested on this one. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation that works both for CSS and Javascript. You just need to wrap it up like they do on the example you gave and create the bar graph.

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

Source: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: It doesn't do really the job .. I think that's it's impossible to detect the event for css